# Space image inside the circle

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/obzpLy1g/

Basically its an image inside a red circle. Would it be possible to space the image inside the circle

My html looks like this

```
<div style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-image: url('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41erGZf8kNL._AC_.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-origin: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    "></div>
```

My code do not give the image inside the circle a padding of 20px like i would have wanted.

Comment: The answers received so far all seem to have some merit but have been down voted or deleted. I suspect therefore we may be misinterpreting what you want as the final result. Could you provide a picture so we can be sure? [Whatever I do the head of a chicken is cut off an maybe that is the problem with the exisiting answers??].

Comment: I see you accepted an answer that involve adding pseudo element but you don't really need it if you want to have that visual result. I have updated my answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you get the whole of the image inside the circle, but still have padding of 20px all round, this snippet puts the image as background to the before pseudo element. That way it doesn't get clipped by the radius setting of the div.

It sets the size to contain to ensure all the image is visible. The given image is rectangular rather than square so it doesn't seem to make sense to clip it if you don't want a headless chicken.

```css
div::before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% - (2 * var(--padding)));
  height: calc(100% - (2 * var(--padding)));
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41erGZf8kNL._AC_.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      --padding: 20px;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
    "></div>
```

Note: the snippet gives the div a gray background for demo purposes, just to make clear the exact positioning and size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clip the image to the `content-box` not the `padding-box`

```html
<div style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-image: url('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41erGZf8kNL._AC_.jpg');
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center;
      background-origin: content-box;
      background-clip: content-box;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Is this what you are looking for? Run the snippet !

```html
<div style="
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-image: url('https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41erGZf8kNL._AC_.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-origin: padding-box;
      background-clip: content-box;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    "></div>
```

`background-clip:content-box;`

#### Clip the image inside `content-box`

let me know if it is not what you asked I will try again.